# smarty template variables not accessible in php tags

Tags: php, smarty

I have this following line of code in a smarty template file `{$date} {php}global $date; echo "-".$date."-"; echo date("Y",strtotime(date("Y-m-d",$date)." -1 year")){/php}`.   It gives this output:

> March 8, 2018--1968

This is not the behaviour I want.  The behaviour I want is

> March 8, 2018-March 8, 2018-2017

How do I modify my smarty code such that it behaves the way I expect it to?  For some reason, my smarty template variables are not accessible within the php tags.

I'm using Smarty version 2.6.7

Comment: Can't you just use Smarty's [`date_format()`](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl)?

Comment: @PatrickQ I tried this `{$date|date_format:"%Y -1 year"}`, and that gave me `2018 -1 year` when I what I really wanted is `2017`.  What am I doing wrong?  How do I take the `$date` variable and subtract one year from it?

Comment: I don't have an install of Smarty to test, but I'd try `{"\`$date\` - 1 year"|strtotime|date_format:"%Y"}`.  If you do some searching, you should be able to find some posts/articles about date formatting and manipulation in Smarty.